# date +%s glitches

Tags: linux, cron, time, date, epoch-time

I have a strange issue I'm starting to troubleshoot and wondered if anyone would have any helpful tips.

I have a cronjob executed every minute that executes a script and appends the output to a file on a filer. The job prints the current timestamp since epoch (date +%s) and the current uptime uptime (including the current system time) to a file.

The script is:

```
DATE=`date +%s`
UPTIME=`uptime`
echo "$DATE;$UPTIME"
```

And what I get is:

```
1325770921; 14:42:01 up 17 days
1325775379; 14:43:01 up 17 days
1325771041; 14:44:01 up 17 days
```

Notice how the timestamp in the middle is ~1 hour 15 minutes off.. any ideas as to the cause?

Comment: Is this in a virtual machine?   I suspect that the internal clock is drifting.

Comment: I ask... because "uptime" is measured using the hardware clock's initial time (on boot) and then subtracting the current hardware clock's time.  The Date algorithm is based on clock-cycles... (which is very odd... I know) ... and in virtual machines especially... this can drift as a fixed number of cycles doesn't take a constant amount of time anymore.

Comment: Has this happened more than once or is that a one-off glitch?  If it has happened before, is it regular or irregular?

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes this is a VM and yes it's happening quite frequently but not with any precise frequency that I'd be able to notice. The interesting thing is that if you look at the data above - the third timestamp is spot on - it's just as if the second one jumps into the future but then a minute later we're back on track - are there any clock correction mechanisms that might be fixing things once they drift off?

Comment: VM management systems usually have their own methods for keeping the time correct in the VMs.  Here's somewhere to start for [VMWare](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427).

Answer (score 1):

You mention in the comments that you are running a virtual machine. Virtual machines should have an NTP client running continually correcting for the proper time and date. If you don't do this, the interaction between the physical hardware clock and the virtual clock can get messy and the time will drift.

Really, *every* system should run NTP, but in virtual machines it is critical instead of just recommended.

Linux and BSD environments should have both NTPd and OpenNTPd available; you didn't mention which environment you are using.

Comment: We are running NTP afaik - notice the time goes back "exactly" to where it should be - to be true I wonder if it isn't some race condition between NTP and my cronjob - maybe adding a sleep to the job would solve this - I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your VM it could be that your `Guest` clock is tied to the `hosts`.

Please check

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

See http://wiki.debian.org/Xen after heading 'clocksource/0: Time went backwards'. 
It's gives you some workaround to try if you happen to on a Xen VM.

We've had some funny time jumping with these and depending on how old your dom0 is and how new your domU guests are we've had to use `xen` and `jiffies` to make the time behave and to be able to really use ntp on guests.